# Why do the Quantity Up and Down arrows only show on some of the product pages and not others on BigCommerce's Cornerstone Light theme?

Tags: html, user-interface, svg, button, bigcommerce

The Quantity up and down arrows svg, which use the following code:

```
                <button class="button button--icon" data-action="dec">
                    <span class="is-srOnly">Decrease Quantity:</span>
                    <i class="icon" aria-hidden="true">
                        <svg>
                            <use xlink:href="#icon-keyboard-arrow-down"/>
                        </svg>

                <button class="button button--icon" data-action="inc">
                    <span class="is-srOnly">Increase Quantity:</span>
                    <i class="icon" aria-hidden="true">
                        <svg>
                            <use xlink:href="#icon-keyboard-arrow-up"/>
                        </svg>
                    </i>
                </button>
```

only show up on select products on our website (Buttons still work). I haven't been able to figure out if there is a pattern or a method to why they are showing up or not showing up, but some of them look like this:

[image: Working buttons]

and others look like this:

[image: Broken Buttons]

If more info is needed, please let me know, but this is all I could find that was relevant, but I could be mistaken.

Comment: The page doesn't have an element with id icon-keyboard-arrow-down

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The arrows are generated by JavaScript. If they are showing on some pages and not on others, that would lead me to believe there is a JavaScript error on the page where they are not loading. Open your Chrome DevTools console to check for any JavaScript errors, and try to resolve them. Without a link to the site, I cannot say specifically what the error is that is breaking this.

Comment: https://www.bobjohnson.com/toughbook-cf-33-intel-core-i5-6300u-2-40ghz/ would be an example of a page not working

Comment: It looks like the issue is coming from the related products or the "Customers Also Viewed." The error is not very readable, but something to do with Slick carousel not initializing properly. If you had a developer work on this section of your theme, I would reach out to them. If it is not customized, it is likely an error with the theme, and I would reach out to that theme's developer.